# Master port is disabled from Public IP, MySQL log is not getting refreshed

Tags: mysql, replication

My MySQL Replication setup is over internet.
Master is on Public IP.

If I stop mysql service in master, immediately an error message is thrown in slave. And when I start the service, slave is immediately connecting to master and replication is happening well.

But if the port is disabled from the Public IP, no error is getting thrown in slave log and showing as connection success, but data is not getting replicating from master to slave. And if the port is enabled for Public IP, it is showing as connection success and data is not getting replicating from master to slave.

Until I restart the slave, data is not getting replicating from Master to Slave.
Once I restart the slave, every thing goes fine.

Can I know, what is the reason for not getting replicated.

And Is there any way to come to know the master status from the slave, when this type of behavior occurs.

Also is there any option to stop slave when master port is disabled.

Please help me on this.

I am using MySQL version 5.0.24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem stems from the Slave's IO Thread. Sometimes, it has the nasty habit of playing dumb and not properly checking or pinging the master.

[MySQL 5.5's semisynchronous replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-semisync.html) allows you to [have the master time itself out and degrade back to asynchronous replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout). Slaves running semisynchronous replication should have a more sensitive IO Thread now.

Concerning your particular situation, you are using MySQL 5.0.24 ??? That's a very old version. There are two bug reports ([Bug1](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30703) and [Bug2](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=51089)) discussing this.

[It just dawned on me that you asked this question earlier and DTest answered it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6365/can-we-capture-only-slave-io-running-in-show-slave-status-in-mysql/6366#6366). Giving credit where credit is due, the bug reports came from his answer.

It would be nice to to be informed when the Public IP is being disabled from Slave access. That way, you could run `STOP SLAVE;` on the slave in advance.

You also asked is there a way to come to know the master status from the slave, when this type of behavior occurs.

Here is a typical `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.64.80.136
                  Master_User: replicant
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000019 <<------
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 277892198 <<------
               Relay_Log_File: relay-bin.000058
                Relay_Log_Pos: 37535484
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000019 <<------
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 277892198 <<------
              Relay_Log_Space: 277892637 <<------
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please note the following:

- **Master_Log_File** : Log file from Master whose latest SQL was last copied to relay logs
- **Read_Master_Log_Pos** : Log position within `Master_Log_File` whose latest SQL was last copied to relay logs
- **Relay_Master_Log_File** : Log file from Master whose SQL was last executed from the relay logs
- **Exec_Master_Log_Pos** : Log position within `Relay_Master_Log_File` whose SQL was last executed from the relay logs

If none of these value are moving, that could mean the all SQL is processed or that the slave is currently processing an SQL statement in the SQL thread that came from position `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` of the Master Log `Relay_Master_Log_File`.

Now, look at `Relay_Log_Space`. This number represents the sum total of all filesizes for all relay logs. If `Slave_IO_Running` is Yes and `Relay_Log_Space` is not changing, then go check the master by running `SHOW MASTER STATUS;`. It should like something like this:

```
mysql> show master status;
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position  | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000019 | 682563021 |              |                  |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If the Master's (File,Position) of `SHOW MASTER STATUS;` is beyond the Slave's (Master_Log_File,Read_Master_Log_Pos) of `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`, then the IO Thread on the Slave is dead for intents and purposes, even if Slave_IO_Running is Yes.

Comment: Thanks for answering this. As all of my clients are using old version, I am not able to update to latest MySQL version. And coming to the monitoring, you had explained clearly how can we come to know if server goes down. 
But I need some other way to know the actual problem as I will be giving to my customer who will be monitoring and is not aware of any DBA activities. 
So please help me out of this.