# MySQL Master not sending events to another Master

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6

We have Master-Master Replication and it is configured correctly as it transmit data for certain period of time and after that it does not send further events till we stop/start slave on both nodes.

When I run `Show Slave Status\G`, it displays

- `Seconds_Behind_Master` as 0
- `Slave_SQL_Running` as `Yes`
- `Slave_IO_Running` as `Yes`
- `server_id` is also different for both nodes.

My Server Info

- MySQL Version is 5.6.23
- Windows Server 2012

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please add a full output of things like your my.ini, server versions, and `SHOW MASTER STATUS` and `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` of both servers before and after a write command/you observe the issue. Check also the error log for issues.

Comment: no errors in log error log as well..it does not update the position while reading for binlog when it stops reading events till issue of stop/start slave. Version and os already given in question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be one of two things

- Slave I/O Thread is encountering Network Issues
- Slave I/O is Playing Possum (pretending to be dead)

[Derek Downey](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/180/derek-downey) and I have written posts about the flaky behavior of the Slave's I/O Thread

- `Oct 17, 2011` : [Master port is disabled from Public IP, MySQL log is not getting refreshed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6882/master-port-is-disabled-from-public-ip-mysql-log-is-not-getting-refreshed/6891#6891)
- `Sep 30, 2011` : [Can we capture only Slave_IO_Running in SHOW SLAVE STATUS in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6365/can-we-capture-only-slave-io-running-in-show-slave-status-in-mysql/6366#6366))

According to the Bug Reports on this phenomenon, it was supposedly fixed.

See ([Bug #30703](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30703) and [Bug #51089](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=51089))

If this bug is happening to you, someone missed a patch making MySQL 5.6.23.

I have three suggestions

- Drop back to MySQL 5.6.22 or 5.6.21 or last version of MySQL 5.6 where replication was working
- Use [MySQL 5.6's heartbeat option when running CHANGE MASTER TO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/change-master-to.html).
- Implement [semisynchronous replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-semisync.html)

As for the Network

- Check Network For Dropped Packets
- Check the NIC Card
- Use separate NIC card for Replication Traffic

Other that what I have just said, sorry I don't have a silver bullet for this one :-(

Comment: seems like change master to MASTER_HEARTBEAT_PERIOD did the trick. Doesn't know why would have to use this explicitly in 5.6.23 because i have done this without using this feature in previous versions. Anyways thanks alot for your great help.